# How can i check on which ip my pc is connected to the router that my android device is connected to it also?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, android-studio

My android device is connected by wifi to the same network my pc is connected with a cable to the router. My android is connected also to the router by wifi.

On my router settings i see both my android on ip 10.0.0.3 and my pc on ip 10.0.0.2

In my program i added another ip to the array just for the testing.
What i want to do is in my android device when i click on a button to loop over the array and find on which ip my pc is connected to the router.

This is what i did in the onClick button event:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                try
                {
                    int timeout = 1000;
                  for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)
                  {
                      if (InetAddress.getByName(ipaddresses[i]).isReachable(timeout))
                      {
                          System.out.println(ipaddresses[i] + " is reachable");
                          text.setText("Connection success");
                          break;
                      }
                  }

                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
            }
```

In the ipaddresses array the first string in index [0] is "10.0.0.2"
So when i'm running my program clicking the button it should find that my pc is connected to this ip.

But instead it's jumping to the catch and disply the Connection Failed.

Why the connection failed if i know my pc is connected to 10.0.0.2 ?

I tried to do it this way with a thread:

```
try
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            int timeout = 1000;
                            for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (InetAddress.getByName(ipaddresses[i]).isReachable(timeout))
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(ipaddresses[i] + " is reachable");
                                        text.setText("Connection success");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();

                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                }
```

But when i is 0 i = 0 then it should get to the break; since in ipaddresses array index 0 is 10.0.0.2 my pc ip address. But instead it's doing the for again and now i = 1 something is wrong.

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: When it's getting to the catch i see near it in gray color e: "andoird.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" and in the LogCat i see the text scrolling nonstop not sure how to find and copy the exception message from there.

Comment: So, you can't do network operations on the UI thread. You would have to create another thread or use an AsyncTask.

Comment: I added a thread now: But when i is 0 i = 0 then it should get to the break; since in ipaddresses array index 0 is 10.0.0.2 my pc ip address. But instead it's doing the for again and now i = 1 something is wrong. Updated my question with the code i'm trying now.

Comment: Another thing i did the inner catch inside the thread so if it dosen't find the first ip address as my pc ip so jump to the catch and show the Connection Failed but it's not getting there it's just keep doing the loop untill finish. Nothing is working in my code as i wanted.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: No exceptions. After i changed it using a thread look at my question. Now i don't have exceptions but using a break point i see it's just not getting to the break; when it's on the 10.0.0.2 ip address. The FOR loop just continue and then the program just continue. Can't figure out why it's not getting inside the if (InetAddress.getByName(.... when i = 0 since this is my pc ip address 10.0.0.2

Comment: I tried to set now the timout for 10000 but still it dosen't work.